# UITableViewCell subview (left side)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

Is it possible to implement a subview of a UITableViewCell on the left side of the cell that crossfades when the table enters the editing mode?
Another problem I face is that the bounds of the cell.textLabel are read-only. Is it possible to use some sort of inset for that label? (Because I, like mentioned above, want to use a View on the left side)

Edit: How do I perform an action (in this case fade a subview) when the whole table enters editingmode? (Not through a swipe over a cell). The reason why I want to implement this is because the tableview shows the "-" button on the left side of the cells if it is in editingmode. (I want to show my own button on the left side of the cells if editing=NO, fade it out if editing=YES and show it again if the tableView leaves editingmode (editing=NO))

A first thought directs me to something like this:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if(editing) {
        //fade out my own button
    } else {
        //show my own button
    }
}
```

But I would have to loop through all the cells and I think this leads to a substantial performance worsening. What do you think?

Comment: I am not really understanding what you want, but did you see the *[Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I created a custom UILabel that I used instead of the default UITableView textLabel and added a custom button on the left side. In the setEditing method I fade this button in/out.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the Editing Accessory View of a UITableViewCell.  See the [editingAccessoryView property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for information on this.  More information can be found in the [Customizing Cells section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) of the [TableView Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

The label within the content view of a table view cell is read-only so you can not reassign it but its properties are mutable.  You can actually move the label around within the bounds of the table view cell.  It's probably confusing to grasp, but have a look at the [Characteristics of Cell Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW10) section of the Table View Programming Guide.  In it, the bounding boxes for each of the nested views are shown (not all of them are always visible).  For your purposes, a good exercise would be to set the background color of each subview of a UITableViewCell to a different color and then try to adjust the sizes of them.   Doing so and understanding what's going on will probably let you achieve the end-result that you desire.